# HotswapAgent not working & throws "not valid, removing path="

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, dcevm, hotswapagent

I’m facing an issue and I could use some help, please.
My ENV:

**Dcevm-11.0.9+1 (2020-11-24)
Intellij 202.6397.94
Centos7
Spring-Boot 2.1.6.RELEASE**

And I followed these guides :
https://github.com/HotswapProjects/HotswapAgent
&
https://github.com/TravaOpenJDK/trava-jdk-11-dcevm

What I get after recompile my classes is like:

**HOTSWAP AGENT: 19:49:11.740 WARNING (org.hotswap.agent.watch.nio.WatcherNIO2) - Watcher on <PATH_TO_MY_CHANGED_CLASS> not valid, removing path=**

And my **services **not updating****. In addition, if it helps, I attached a part of the application logs on start.

```
HOTSWAP AGENT: 19:44:12.986 INFO (org.hotswap.agent.config.PluginRegistry) - Plugin 'org.hotswap.agent.plugin.spring.SpringPlugin' initialized in ClassLoader 'jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@3b192d32'.
HOTSWAP AGENT: 19:44:12.987 INFO (org.hotswap.agent.plugin.spring.SpringPlugin) - Spring plugin initialized - Spring core version '5.1.8.RELEASE'

2020-11-18 19:44:13.261  INFO 31796 --- [           main] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2020-11-18 19:44:13.262  INFO 31796 --- [           main] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
HOTSWAP AGENT: 19:44:13.336 INFO (org.hotswap.agent.config.PluginRegistry) - Plugin 'org.hotswap.agent.plugin.hibernate.HibernatePlugin' initialized in ClassLoader 'jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@3b192d32'.
HOTSWAP AGENT: 19:44:13.647 INFO (org.hotswap.agent.plugin.spring.SpringPlugin) - Registering basePackage com.wow.hrmanagement.*
HOTSWAP AGENT: 19:44:13.885 INFO (org.hotswap.agent.plugin.spring.SpringPlugin) - Registering basePackage com.wow.commons.*

HOTSWAP AGENT: 19:44:16.339 INFO (org.hotswap.agent.config.PluginRegistry) - Plugin 'org.hotswap.agent.plugin.tomcat.TomcatPlugin' initialized in ClassLoader 'TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader
  context: ROOT
  delegate: true
----------> Parent Classloader:
jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@3b192d32
'.
HOTSWAP AGENT: 19:44:16.339 INFO (org.hotswap.agent.plugin.tomcat.TomcatPlugin) - Tomcat plugin initialized - Tomcat version '9.0.21.0'
```

Comment: I have this issue as well...